# What does performance do on service buildings?

Tags: surviving-mars

What does performance do on service buildings? I want to know if performance increases the comfort (or sanity) bonus of the colonists who use it or if it increases the speed of colonists using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. A performance bonus on a service building manifests as a higher service comfort. The use profile and benefits are they same, but you can get the comfort kick at higher minimum comforts.

Service comfort is the maximum comfort a colonist can have, and still benefit from the service, so this is still valuable if you're going for ultra-high comfort.